# Reading from a binary file (big endian) into a struct with multiple data types

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream

I have a binary format that has a bunch of repeating 32-bit integers (in big endian order) similar to this:

`[int a, int b, int c][int a, int b, int c][...]`

I have this simplified a lot. There are actually way more values in the struct/binary file (but the binary file is all integers). What I ultimately want to do to read from the file and and create structs that looks like this:

```cpp
struct Foo
{
  int a;
  float b;
  float c;
};
```

Where the floats are just the integer values for b and c multiplied by 0.1.

My Initial thought is I should overloading the `std::ifstream operator>>` for the `Foo` struct?

I read this [post](https://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html) about reading an int from big-endian streams.

```
i = (data[0]<<0) | (data[1]<<8) | (data[2]<<16) | (data[3]<<24);
```

but I'm not sure how I would scale this to a bigger struct?

The other method I thought of is to just use `infile.read()`, and then loop over the the words in the struct and swap the bytes, but this would only get me a struct of ints.

I feel like I need to write a stream overload that reads in 4 bytes. Swaps them and if the struct value is a float multiply the int by 0.10 (not sure if I need to cast it first).

I can do all of this quite easily in c, but just trying to learn idomatic c++ ways of doing things.

Comment: For converting big-endian 32-bit-integer data to the host CPU's native-endian format (whatever it may be), ntohl() is your friend:  https://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohl

Comment: Whether you use `operator>>` or any other function as the interface doesn't seem related to the rest of your question which is concerned with how to implement the operation. That last part really just works the same in C++ as in C (just that you use `std::ifstream::read` instead of `fread`) and the first part is basically a matter of style.

Comment: I usually write a `for` something like  `for (size_t index = 0; index < sizeof(val); index++)` that shifts `val` and ORs in the new byte. I used to do complicated stuff that was lighting fast, but then I profiled and found when the compiler was done with it, the idiotic `for` loop was just as fast. Fast, stupid code is always better than fast complicated code. If `val`'s type is a template parameter the loop scales as far as you need to go with no added effort.

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply use fread().  Then loop with htonl() calls.  Since everything is 32-bits, if you want to be portable, I'd use int32_t instead of int, as int's size depends upon the implementation.  Since the data is techically int32 data, I'd make the structure look like:

```
union wrapper {
    int32_t i;
    float f;
};
```

and then make your structure:

```
struct Foo
{
  int a;
  wrapper b;
  wrapper c;
};
```

In C++, I'd also do a static assert that sizeof(union wrapper) == sizeof(int32_t).

I'd also call stat() to get the size of the file and confirm it's a multiple of struct Foo, before reading the data.